# Is there a javascript code to select options in <select> without clearing selected disabled options?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
<select id="idsite" name="sites-list" size="10" multiple style="width:100px;">
    <option value="1" disabled>SITE</option>
    <option value="2" disabled selected>SITE</option>
    <option value="3">SITE</option>
    <option value="4">SITE</option>
    <option value="5" disabled>SITE</option>
    <option value="6" selected>SITE</option>
    <option value="7">SITE</option>
    <option value="8">SITE</option>
    <option value="9">SITE</option>
</select>
```

By default, there are 3 disabled options (one of them selected). When I click a non-disable option, the `<option value="2" disabled selected>SITE</option>` option is not selected (clear selection). Is there any javascript code, not using jquery, that solves this problem? thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in a `<select>` with the `multiple` attribute you have to use Ctrl + click (at least on Windows) to select multiple items. A click without holding the Ctrl key removes the existing selections and only the clicked option will be selected.

More details: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#selecting_multiple_options)

Comment: command + click on Mac. This is why in my previous comment I thought nothing was wrong ... because I was doing this out of habit.